# Python проверка на русские буквы

Tags: python, строки

Если в программе на python у меня есть массив 
`alphabet = ["а","б","в","г","д","е","ё","ж","з","и","й","к","л","м","н","о",
            "п","р","с","т","у","ф","х","ц","ч","ш","щ","ъ","ы","ь","э","ю","я"]`
то могу я проверить переменную-строку text на отсутствие русских букв таким образом

```
if text not in alphabet:
    print('False')
```

Если нет, то как можно это сделать, (желательно без регулярных выражений). Заранее спасибо!

Comment: *желательно без регулярных выражений* Какие основания не использовать самый подходящий для решения задачи инструмент?

Comment: потому что данный код используется в теле функции

Comment: Если Вам кто-то сказал, что регулярные выражения можно использовать только в main - не верьте...

Comment: Юзайте функцию `range`, за место перечисления всего алфавита.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def match(text, alphabet=set('абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя')):
    return not alphabet.isdisjoint(text.lower())

print(match('test')) # False
print(match('тест')) # True
print(match('123Ы')) # True
print(match(''))     # False
```

Answer (score 2):

Раз вами принято решение не использовать регулярные выражения, можно получить булево значение от пересечения объектов `set`. Если в тексте есть русские буквы - в пересечении будут объекты, результат - `True`. Если русских букв в тексте нет - `False`

```py
alphabet = ["а","б","в","г","д","е","ё","ж","з","и","й","к","л","м","н","о",
            "п","р","с","т","у","ф","х","ц","ч","ш","щ","ъ","ы","ь","э","ю","я"]

text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
text_ru = 'Мама мыла раму'

print(bool(set(alphabet).intersection(set(text.lower()))))
print(bool(set(alphabet).intersection(set(text_ru.lower()))))
```

Запись можно немного сократить, если изначально создать алфавит в объекте `set`, а не `list`:

```
alphabet = {"а","б","в","г","д","е","ё","ж","з","и","й","к","л","м","н","о",
            "п","р","с","т","у","ф","х","ц","ч","ш","щ","ъ","ы","ь","э","ю","я"}

text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
text_ru = 'Мама мыла раму'

print(bool(alphabet.intersection(set(text.lower()))))
print(bool(alphabet.intersection(set(text_ru.lower()))))
```

Результат:

```
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Через список:

```
your_str = 'hi'
rus_letters = ["а","б","в","г","д","е","ё","ж","з","и","й","к","л","м","н","о","п","р","с","т","у","ф","х","ц","ч","ш","щ","ъ","ы","ь","э","ю","я"]
def check_str(string):
    return all([i not in rus_letters for i in string])

print(check_str(your_str))
```

> `True`

Regex:

```
import re 

def has_cyrillic(text):
    return bool(re.search('[а-яА-Я]', text))
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255244/python-check-if-a-string-contains-cyrillic-characters)

Comment: А для такой строки второй код будёт работать: "Ёё"?

Answer (score 0):

Как вы и просили без регулярок

```
input_str = "testtest test1"
def check_for_russian(string):
    alphabet = ["а","б","в","г","д","е","ё","ж","з","и","й","к","л","м","н","о", "п","р","с","т","у","ф","х","ц","ч","ш","щ","ъ","ы","ь","э","ю","я"]
    for one_char in string:
        if one_char in alphabet:
            return True
    return False

print(check_for_russian(input_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

При использовании библиотеки re, нужно иметь ввиду, что мы теряем в данном случае буквы ё и Ё.

```
import re 

def has_cyrillic(text):
    return bool(re.search('[а-яА-Я]', text))

has_cyrillic('ё')
```

Альтернативный вариант в использовании функции ord() для символа, возвращающей число из таблицы символов Unicode, представляющее его позицию.

```
for i in ('Ая'):
  print(ord(i))
```

Интервал от 1040 до 1103 включает символы кириллицы. Плюс 1105 и 1025 для ё и Ё соответственно.